# Need help: Timezone related Oracle SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your help in understanding the below query.

```
   SELECT To_date(To_char(( ( To_timestamp_tz(From_tz(Cast(l_end_date AS TIMESTAMP)
                                           ,
                                                  dbtimezone))
                                        ) AT
                                        TIME
                                                ZONE ( l_time_zone ) ),
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
               ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
FROM   dual
where l_end_date = 31-Dec-2018
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, ultimately it converts the date `31-Dec-2018` at midnight into whatever local timezone date you indicate with `l_time_zone`. E.g., for me with `dbtimezone` = `+00:00` and `l_time_zone` set to `Australia/Sydney` I get `31/12/2018 11:00:00 AM`.

But to fully understand you may just want to look at each function's documentation:

- [DBTIMEZONE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions041.htm)
- [TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions202.htm)
- [FROMTZ](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1088.htm)
- [TO_DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions191.htm)
- [TO_CHAR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions188.htm)
- [AT TIME ZONE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG264)